# How to get records by only month condtion on date column

Tags: linq

I tried like below but not executing..

```
var LeaveLimitCheck = db.LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORM.SingleOrDefault(em => em.LEAVE_TYPE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.LEAVE_TYPE_ID
                                    && em.EMPLOYEE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.EMPLOYEE_ID
                                    && em.FROM_DATE.ToString("MM")) == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.FROM_DATE.ToString("MM"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not executing"? Is it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `ToString()` , but it depends on your dll version.

the correct approach is to use the `Month` property of the `Datetime`

Comparing two datetimes by month

```
Datetime1.Month == Datetime2.Month
```

or if your Datetime is a nullable

```
Datetime1.Value.Month == Datetime2.Value.Month
```

so a correct linq query would be for example

```
(from p in Source where p.DT.Value.Month == RequestedDatetime.Value.Month select p)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ToString()` in linq. Please try this:

```
var LeaveLimitCheck = db.LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORM.SingleOrDefault(em => em.LEAVE_TYPE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.LEAVE_TYPE_ID
                                    && em.EMPLOYEE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.EMPLOYEE_ID
                                    && em.FROM_DATE.Value.Month) == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.FROM_DATE.Value.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the parentheses. The date comparison was happening outside of the query.

Furthermore, instead of getting the month-string and comparing that, compare on the `Month` property of the `DateTime` value instead.

Also, I would move the month you have to find outside of the query, just for the sake of readability.

```
int monthToCheck = LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.FROM_DATE.Month;

var LeaveLimitCheck = db.LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORM.SingleOrDefault(em => em.LEAVE_TYPE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.LEAVE_TYPE_ID
                        && em.EMPLOYEE_ID == LEAVE_APPLICATION_FORMObj.EMPLOYEE_ID
                        && em.FROM_DATE.Month == monthToCheck);
```